# How to disable "render outside safe area" programatically?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

My game renders outside the safe area by default, it works for most cases where the notch is absent or in the middle, but some devices have their notches either to the left or to the right and then it breaks my UI.

This option can be enabled/disabled through the Unity Editor player settings, but I want to disable it through the code based on a decision using the `Screen.cutouts`.

How do I disable this option programatically? If there is no API, is there any way to disable it via reflection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to disable the rendering outside the safe area:

```
private void DisableExtendedArea() {
    AndroidJavaClass unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject unityWindow = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow");
    AndroidJavaObject unityWindowAttributes = unityWindow.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getAttributes");
    AndroidJavaObject unityLayoutParams = new AndroidJavaClass("android/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams");

    unityWindowAttributes.Set<int>("layoutInDisplayCutoutMode", unityLayoutParams.GetStatic<int>("LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER"));
    unityWindow.Call("setAttributes", unityWindowAttributes);
}
```

You might need to run this on the UI thread:

```
    AndroidJavaClass unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    unityActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(DisableExtendedArea));
```

Comment: How to do it vice-versa? I mean, once I have enabled Render in safe area, now how to programmatically disable it, ie. render outside safe area?

Comment: You can replace LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER with any other constant mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS